# How to change class type of View Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created a new project, the ViewController.swift is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I created a table view in the view controller so I wanted to change the class type into UITableViewController, here's what I did:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Then the program goes signal SIGABART, what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

A `UITableViewController` is a strange beast. It can ONLY manage a single table view, and nothing else. If you want your view controller to manage a combination of different views (labels, buttons, etc. as well as a table view) then make it a normal `UIViewController`, not a `UITableViewController`.

If you want to change a view controller to a different class you have to both change the class in your source file and then select the view controller in Interface Builder's "Identity inspector" and change it's class there as well. That's probably what is crashing your program.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems.  Your `ViewController` is a subset of `UITableViewController`, but you are missing some required methods.  Also, in your Storyboard you don't have a `UITableViewController`, you have a `UIViewController` that has a `UITableView`.  They're not the same thing.

If you don't want to delete the whole project and start over, the quickest way to get where you want to go from here is to:

1. Delete *ViewController.swift* from your project.
2. Select **File->New->File...** from the Menu.  Click on **Cocoa Touch Class** and then <kbd>Next</kbd>.
3. Give your class a name (`ViewController` if you really want to stick with that) and make it a subclass of `UITableViewController`.
4. Open your *Main.storyboard* file.  Click on your `ViewController` and delete it.
5. Drag out a new **Table View Controller**.
6. Select the TableViewController, and then in the *Identity Inspector* on the right set the class to the class name you chose in step 3 (e.g. ViewController).
7. In the *Attributes Inspector*, check the box next to **Is Initial View Controller**.

Now you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your storyboard as well, you probably have your new class UITableViewController connect to a ViewController in the storyboard, this cause swift to call outlets that does not exist and crash.

Answer (score 0):

if you have closely look on the **crash** you will see something like this

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] loaded the "SomeID" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

That means if your extending the `UITableViewController` in class file you must use the same thing in Storyboard viewcontroller too.Because `UITableViewController`give in-built `UITableView`.